# java class instantiated as 2d array

Tags: java

I came across this line in the cards example of oracle trails:

```
public Cards[][] cards =new Cards[int suits][int ranks];
```

no explanation given despite the deviation from:

```
Cards cards=new Cards(int suits,int ranks);
```

this is a new concept to me. Somebody please explain the 2D array or give me links to pages that explain such an instance?.

Comment: Have you tried googling "2d array" or something similar? I can't imagine there are no perfectly clear examples somewhere

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/java-use-arrays-with-two-dimensions-or-more.html

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm) 
 2D array,which is actually supposed to be an array of arrays is  accepting the same type of assignment for its elements(1D arrays)

```
    int[][] twoD = new int[4][];  
    twoD[0] = new int[1]{1};  
    twoD[1] = new int[2]{2,3};  
    twoD[2] = new int[3]{4,5,6);  
    twoD[3] = new int[4]{7,8,9,10};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first line you create a 2d dimensional array of **uninitialized** instances of a Cards class.

The size of each dimension is defined by the number you input in the braces (don't know why you need the `int` in there, does it even compile ?)

You need to initialize each cell by `cards[i][j] = new Cards(suits, ranks);` in order to be able to access the cards in that cell. (where `i` and `j` are in the array boundaries)

You second line is a creation of a single instance of class `Cards`. The `suits` and `ranks` arguments that you are passing are due to the constructor definition of the class `Cards` as opposed to the definition of a 2d array (where the values in the braces define the size of each dimension of the array)

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
public Cards[][] cards = new Cards[int suits][int ranks];
```

does not instantiate any new objects of type `Cards`. However it defines a new 2D array to store objects of type `Cards` in. A 2D array can be considered as a chess board. On every field of this chess board (it's size is `suits`x`ranks`) an object of type `Cards` can be placed.

On the other side, the statement

```
Cards c = new Cards(int suits,int ranks);
```

would instantiate one new object of type `Cards` (at least if `int suits` and `int ranks` would be replaced with proper values). After the creation of this object, it could be stored in our defined 2D array:

```
cards[0][0] = c;
```

This statement would place our object `c` of type `Cards` in the top left field of our chess board.

Summing up, a 2D array is basically a data container (like a `List`) which can store objects of the given type.